# setting library include paths in c++

Tags: c++, macos, gd

I just installed gd2 using mac ports (sudo install gd2), which installed libraries in the following places:

```
/opt/local/include/gd.h
/opt/local/lib/libgd.dylib (link)
/opt/local/lib/libgd.la
/opt/local/lib/libgd.a
```

Here is my make file also:

```
dev: main.o
    g++ -L/opt/local/lib -I/opt/local/include -lgd -lpng -lz -ljpeg -lfreetype -lm main.o -o heatmap

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp
```

So when I create my c++ app I add '#include "gd.h"', which throws:

```
main.cpp:4:16: error: gd.h: No such file or directory
```

If I set gd.h as an absolute path (as above)(not a solution, but was curious), I am thrown:

```
g++ -L/opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib main.o -o heatmap
Undefined symbols:
  "_gdImagePng", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_gdImageLine", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_gdImageColorAllocate", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
      _main in main.o
  "_gdImageDestroy", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_gdImageCreate", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_gdImageJpeg", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
```

So, I understand this means that ld can not find the libraries it needs (hence trying to give it hints with the "-L" values). So after giving g++ the -L hints and the absolute path in #include, I can get it to work, but I don't think I have to do this, how can I make g++/ld search int eh right places for the libraries?

Drew J. Sonne.

PS. using:
 - OSX 10.6.2
 - gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646) (dot 1)

EDIT:
Ok, so after taking into account stfanB and Michael's answer, I've recompiled gd into a local directory (`libraries`) and thus, I've changed that first line of my Makefile (I will def check out cmake) to `g++ -L./libraries/lib -I./libraries/include -lgd -lpng -lz -ljpeg -lfreetype -lm main.o -o heatmap`
But I'm still getting `main.cpp:3:16: error: gd.h: No such file or directory`

EDIT:
Thanks all for the answers, here's my final (working) makefile for anyone else who many want an answer:

```
dev: main.o
    g++ -I./libraries/include -L./libraries/lib -lgd -lpng -lz -ljpeg -lfreetype -lm main.o -o heatmap

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -I./libraries/include -c main.cpp
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Rather than invoke g++ directly, I strongly advise you to use [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) (watch the [CMake Google Techtalk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Ut9o4OdSC0) if you'd like to learn more) as it will make your life way easier and greatly simplifies locating and linking against a variety of libraries. That said, I believe the problem with your invocation is that you have not specified the library, which you would do with `-lgd`. Your `-L/opt/local/lib` correctly tells g++ to look in `/opt/local/lib`, but you never told it what to look for. As for finding the appropriate header, you can use `-I/opt/local/include` to put `/opt/local/include` in the compiler's include search path.

If you were to heed my advice to use CMake, doing this would look like:

```
FIND_PACKAGE(GD2 REQUIRED)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${GD2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${GD2_LIBRARY_DIRS})

ADD_EXECUTABLE(heatmap main Heatmap_Map Heatmap_Point)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(heatmap ${GD2_LIBRARIES})
```

If you are interested in learning more about CMake, you might want to take a look at the [C++ Application Project Template](http://code.google.com/p/cpp-project-template/) and [C++ Library Project Template](http://code.google.com/p/cpp-library-project-template/), which make use of the CMake build system. CMake is available through MacPorts via the command "sudo port install cmake".

In case you are not interested in installing CMake, I should also point out that there are some environment variables that you might be interested in knowing about to make your life easier, namely:

- CPATH
- LIBRARY_PATH
- DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH

The CPATH environment variable is much like the PATH environment variable (it is a colon separated list of directories), except that the directories in that variable will automatically be used by gcc and g++ as if they were specified on the commandline with the `-I` flag (i.e. headers will be searched in those paths). The LIBRARY_PATH is the equivalent except that it is as if the folders were given with `-L` (i.e. libraries will automatically be searched in that path). DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH will be used by the dynamic linker (so you should probably include the paths from LIBRARY_PATH into this variable).

You can read more about the [environment variables affecting gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html) at the link.

Comment: I've been using JamPlus lately and quite like it.

Comment: The information you provided about `CPATH`, `LIBRARY_PATH`, and `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` is extremely useful. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

**The answer is quite complicated.**

The short answer, when you compile your own libs/tools place them in some `local` directory such as you used above or `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/include` or even `~/local/lib` and `~/local/include` and always add these to your compiler/linker.

The longer answer - read [Programming Library HOWTO](http://www.dwheeler.com/program-library/Program-Library-HOWTO/t1.html) for Linux that explains what each of the tool involved looks for, from compiler/linker to execution, and have a look at standard [directory structure of Linux system](http://proton.pathname.com/fhs/) which is of course not binding but it's nice to know.

I'm assuming that you have a simple Makefile setup for each of your projects so you don't have to bother with typing all those commands. If you don't I strongly recommend to setup a simple Makefile template that you can reuse for your projects.

**EDIT**:

In your edited answer your paths may be incorrect.

The `.` in your path like `./libraries` specifies current directory, meaning it will look into `libraries` directory in the current directory. If you ment `libraries` directory in root directory then remove the `.` so it should be like this `-L/libraries/lib` and similarly for `-I/libraries/...`

Comment: @Michael it seems like he learned something from other answers as well so probably other answers are not completely irrelevant as you thought.

Comment: @Michael, you got the tick, but stefanB's right, I got more out of the other answers as well. ;-)
@stefanB, yep, I put it in my project dir.

Comment: I'm glad we all were able to help you ... the points are not important

Answer (score 1):

Header include directories need to be specified with -I option (only relative paths needed after this) and linker include directories with -L (relative paths here too).

For libraries, an alternative you could alternatively set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH but the -L method is safer.

Comment: @Sameer, he correctly used the -L flag but forgot to specify a library with -l.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem may be that your -I arguments need to be passed to the compile stage, too.  Maybe something like this?

```
dev: main.o
    g++ -L/opt/local/lib -lgd -lpng -lz -ljpeg -lfreetype -lm main.o -o heatmap

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -I/opt/local/include -c main.cpp
```

Not sure- I haven't used makefiles in 20 years (but as I mentioned in a comment to another post, I find JamPlus quite remarkable in its power).

Anyway- typically your compiler and linker flags will be put into variables and then expanded in the command line, but I'm not sure on the make syntax for that.  Maybe simply:

```
CFLAGS=-I/opt/local/include
LINKFLAGS=-L/opt/local/lib -lgd -lpng -lz -ljpeg -lfreetype -lm 

dev: main.o
    g++ $(LINKFLAGS) main.o -o heatmap

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -c main.cpp
```

Comment: @dash-tom-bang, FYI, CXXFLAGS are typically used for C++ settings while LDFLAGS are used for linker flags. You should use the predefined variable $(CXX) as the C++ compiler rather than hard-coding in g++. Also, main.o : main.cpp is automatically defined. Specifying main.o as a dependency is sufficient to get Make to automatically compiler main.cpp using the default C++ compiler and using any settings specified in CXXFLAGS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use -iquote when using #include "gd.h", see the [gcc directory options documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html).

Also, specifying the include directory in your link stage is pointless.